# Including exposures in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, optimization, mortality

I’m performing a logistic regression in Jupyter Notebook. My target is 1 if a subject died while under observation and 0 if the subject did not die. Not every subject was observed for the same period of time, so the data contains varying levels of exposure. Each subject’s exposure is greater than 0 but less than 1 year. I would like to know if there is an optimization method that would account for the varying exposures. For example, a person with an exposure of 0.5 years might contribute p^0.5 to the likelihood, instead of contributing p. I have been using LogisticRegression from sklearn.linear_model, but I am open to using another method if it will allow me to incorporate the exposures during optimization.

Comment: You'll need to do a survival analysis.

Comment: At the direction of my manager, I have been using logistic regression for this purpose. However, I do feel that this may not be the best approach. I am an actuary, and I am familiar with survival analysis, but I have been asked to look outside of traditional actuarial models (non-parametric models such as Nelson-Aalen or Kaplan-Meier) to perform mortality studies. Ultimately, I need to derive a mortality table that varies by sex and age and obtain some multiplicative adjustments for other demographic variables. Would the CoxPHFitter be a good start?

Comment: Cox regression and Kaplan Meier estimators were built for differential followup.  It really is the best approach.  If you need to adjust for covariates, a cox regression sounds like a good place to start.